# Getting "java.lang.SecurityException: Shell does not have permission to access user 150" when uninstalling apps from Samsung Secure folder using ADB

Tags: applications, adb, samsung, system, uninstallation

I am using Samsung Galaxy A50, Android 11, One UI 3.1. I use Samsung Secure folder. There are many bloatware in it and I could not find a way to uninstall (and disable) them via ADB.

Owner profile user is 0, Secure Folder user is 150.

```
pm uninstall -k --user 150 com.android.chrome 

Exception occurred while executing 'uninstall': java.lang.SecurityException: Shell does not have permission to access user 150
com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser:17947 
android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser:4863 
com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.translateUserId:3125
    at com.android.server.am.UserController.handleIncomingUser(UserController.java:2375)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:17947)
    at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:4863)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.translateUserId(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:3125)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runUninstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2024)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:237)
    at android.os.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:98)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:44)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:26662)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:965)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:839)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:5206)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:5281)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1195)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1159)
```

Comment: Samsung has restricted privileges of adb (shell) user from making changes to packages installed under user 150. There is nothing we can do. This is a design choice (probably to ensure bloat continues to float in the device). Rooting is the only solution to remove bloatware in such situations.

Comment: If no way without root then i should stop searching for answere. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Uninstall the Samsung Secure Folder from the Settings.

Settings -> Lock screen and security -> Secure Folder -> Enter your lock details -> Uninstall.

Refer to [this blog](https://www.samsung.com/za/support/mobile-devices/how-do-i-uninstall-or-remove-the-secure-folder/).

Comment: Perhaps you might want to [edit] and clarify if this is the only solution since the question stated "*I use Samsung Secure folder*", thus uninstalling Samsung Secure Folder might defeat the purpose.

Comment: @AndrewT. I am not sure if this is the only solution, but this worked for me.

Comment: I want to uninstall some bloatwares from secure folder, not uninstall secure folder.

Comment: It works. Confirmed for S22 with Android 13. Jun 10 2023

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same messages after trying to get to the list of packages. Nonetheless, knowing the name of the package, I was able to get rid of bloatware using the standard `pm uninstall -k --user 0` command with no root.

Comment: Are you sure this is what the asker wants? Note that the question is specifically about apps *on Samsung Secure folder (user 150)*, not the owner profile (user 0).

Answer (score 0):

I am expanding on [Ashwin's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/250553/113355). If you have `Secure Folder` enabled (usually by default), in order to uninstall **any other app** or even have permission to do something simple with ADB shell such as listing packages, you need to uninstall secure folder.

Example from before the uninstall for running  `pm list packages | grep google`:
[image: Shell does not have permission to access user 150]

And right after uninstalling `Secure Folder`, I ran the same command and it worked!

[image: pm list packages | grep google]

Now you can uninstall apps via: `adb shell pm uninstall — user 0 com.example.app`

(optionally can add `-k` before `- user` to keep app data)

Comment: Did you able to uninstall any app which can be uninstalled/disabled only via adb insade the secure folder? I am looking for solution to uninstall/disable system apps insade Secure Folder. Adb comments working fine outside secure folder.

Comment: @Halilb1978 your question didn't state that.